# Browser hangs when I try to upload files to S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I have a code which upload user's image to s3 when user login to my application. This is deployed on my staging environment and works perfectly. When I deployed this code to my production environment and tried to login to my application, my browser hangs when user's image is tried to uploaded to s3 and image is also not uploaded to s3. The same happens even when I try to list all my buckets using s3 object. I enabled access logs it also doesn't show anything. 
My staging environment and production environment are different aws instances and both have different sub domain names. Will I have to use different AWS keys for different instances or I am missing something ?

```
    $s3 = new S3($this->AWSAccessKey,$this->AWSSecretKey);
    $bucketName = $this->s3BucketName;
    $s3->getBuckets();  // List all my buckets
    $s3->putFile($data['profilePicture'], $bucketName.'/'.$filename,
                    array(S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
                            S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
                            S3::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER => $contentType)
            );  // Upload file to s3
```

I am using zendservice/amazon package to upload images to s3

Comment: I didn't found any solution for this problem then at last I change my AMI from linux to ubuntu and it works fine.